# PostgreSQL - libpq - bytea and PQexecParams

Tags: c, postgresql, psql

In my C++ code I use libpq for PostgreSQL.

If I run the following queries directly with `PQexec`, I got the correct results `(1 | {{15,20},{78,96}})`

```
WITH bar AS(
  SELECT ST_FromGDALRaster(E'\\x89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d494844520000000200000002080000000057dd52f80000000e49444154089963e46765b11702000107006b50183daf0000000049454e44ae426082'::bytea) AS rast     
)
SELECT (ST_DumpValues(rast)).*
FROM bar
```

or

```
WITH bar AS(
  SELECT ST_FromGDALRaster('\x89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d494844520000000200000002080000000057dd52f80000000e49444154089963e46765b11702000107006b50183daf0000000049454e44ae426082'::bytea) AS rast       
)
SELECT (ST_DumpValues(rast)).*
FROM bar
```

However, when I do:

```
const char* paramValues[1];
int         paramLengths[1];
int         paramFormats[1];

const char * q = R"(        
  WITH bar AS (
     SELECT ST_FromGDALRaster($1::bytea) AS rast        
  )
  SELECT (ST_DumpValues(rast)).*
  FROM bar      
)";

paramValues[0] = "\\x89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d494844520000000200000002080000000057dd52f80000000e49444154089963e46765b11702000107006b50183daf0000000049454e44ae426082";
paramLengths[0] = 72;
paramFormats[0] = 1;   /* parameters are passed in a binary format */

PGresult* res = PQexecParams(conn,
    q,
    1,            /* one param */
    NULL,         /* let the backend deduce param type */
    paramValues,
    paramLengths,
    paramFormats,
    1);           /* ask for binary results */

auto r1 = PQgetvalue(res, 0, 0);
auto r2 = PQgetvalue(res, 0, 0);
```

Values `r1` and `r2` are `nullptr` and no error is returned from the query itself.

If I convert `paramValues[0]` from hexadeximal values to "byte array", I got data starting with chars `‰PNG`. In this case, result is not `nullptr`, but empty string, which is not correct as well.

Any idea what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the type of returned result type

```
PGresult* res = PQexecParams(conn,
    q,
    1,            /* one param */
    NULL,         /* let the backend deduce param type */
    paramValues,
    paramLengths,
    paramFormats,
    0);  /* ask for text results */
```

The result should be `text (0)` instead of `binary (1)`.

As input, byte array is used without escaped symbols.